# Create a table PHP timestamp column

Tags: php, mysql

Good Day,

I am trying to create a php query to create a column named timestamp.

```
$query="CREATE TABLE contacts (id int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,entryCount varchar(15) NOT NULL,web varchar(30) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id),UNIQUE id (id),KEY id_2 (id))";
```

I want to add in a timestamp to it. How can I do it?

Comment: since `ID` is primary key, you can already omit `UNIQUE` because an index is already created on primary key an its already unique. what are you going to do with the timestamp? where are you going to add?

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `contacts` ADD `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
```

Running this query after the first query is run (which creates the table) will add the timestamp column.

Comment: Alternatively, to add that column right into the first column, do this: `CREATE TABLE contacts (id int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,entryCount varchar(15) NOT NULL,web varchar(30) NOT NULL, timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id),UNIQUE id (id),KEY id_2 (id))`

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table `contacts` add `timestamp` timestamp not null
```

use after keyword after which column you want to add e.g. :- after id

use before keyword before which column you want to add e.g. :- before entryCount